# Connected to a VPN on Mac OS X, now what?

Tags: vpn, mac, mac-osx

I'm a little confused as to how to access the VPN network I've just connected to on a mac.

I've successfully connected, but don't know what to do now.

Comment: Please open this question, I had the same issue. It is a real question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends upon what you are trying to do.

If you want to connect to a network share you can use the connect to server option from the finder.  You can enter smb://servername and you will be presented with a list of available resources on the server.

If you want to control another computer you can use the MS RDP client for the [Mac](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/B/9/CB943CBF-DDA8-4580-A711-88AC23763F0E/RDC201_ALL.dmg).

Comment: Where is the connect to server option?

Comment: @kylex It's under the Finder Go menu, or Cmd-K. Now that I've answered that, and even though RTFM is frowned upon as an answer in this forum, I would like to say that the Mac Help menu would have been your friend on this one...

Comment: Perhaps, but using a Mac has been my last option. My original question was how to imitate the l2tp/ipsec settings that the mac has on a Windows box (XP or Vista). Unfortunately while I can connnect to the VPN on a mac, really, I want to connect to via a PC, but have had no luck. My Mac experience in networking is zilch. Thanks for your answer though, it's much appreciated.